# Detect basket ball Hoops and ball tracking

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, tracking

**Detect the hoop**(basket).[To see the samples of "hoop](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=hoop&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.53217764,d.bmk,pv.xjs.s.en_US.Es3CeXuAQeM.O&biw=1600&bih=732&dpr=1&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=1zlFUvLaLYfwrQfQpIHACA#hl=en&q=basketball%20hoop&tbm=isch&um=1)".

**Count** the no of **successful attempts(shoot**) and the **failure** attempts. 
I am using opencv.

**Input**:

1. Camera position will be **static**.
2. The **Portrait** mode videos from any mobile device.

ref:

**What have i tried:**

1. Able to track the basket ball. Still, seeking for a better solution.

**results:**

[image]

**My code:**

```
int main () {

VideoCapture vid(path);

    if (!vid.isOpened())
        exit(-1);
    int i_frame_height = vid.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
    i_height_basketball = i_height_basketball * I_HEIGHT / i_frame_height;
    int fps = vid.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
    Mat mat_black(640, 480, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 0));
    vector <Mat> vec_frames;
    for (int i_push = 0; i_push < I_NO_FRAMES_STORE; i_push++)
        vec_frames.push_back(mat_black);

    vector <Mat> vec_mat_result;
    for (int i_push = 0; i_push < I_RESULT_STORE; i_push++)
        vec_mat_result.push_back(mat_black);

    int count_frame = 0;
    while (true) {
        int clk_start = clock();
        Mat image, result;
        vid >> image;
        if (image.empty())
            break;

        resize(image, image, Size(I_WIDTH, I_HEIGHT));
        image.copyTo(vec_mat_result[count_frame % I_RESULT_STORE]);
        if (count_frame >= 1)
            vec_mat_result[(count_frame - 1) % I_RESULT_STORE].copyTo(result);
        GaussianBlur(image, image, Size(9, 9), 2, 2);
        image.copyTo(vec_frames[count_frame % I_NO_FRAMES_STORE]);

        if (count_frame >= I_NO_FRAMES_STORE - 1) {
            Mat mat_diff_temp(I_HEIGHT, I_WIDTH, CV_32S, Scalar(0));
            for (int i_diff = 0; i_diff < I_NO_FRAMES_STORE; i_diff++) {

                Mat mat_rgb_diff_temp = abs(vec_frames[ (count_frame - 1) % I_NO_FRAMES_STORE ] - vec_frames[ (count_frame - i_diff) % I_NO_FRAMES_STORE ]);
                cvtColor(mat_rgb_diff_temp, mat_rgb_diff_temp, CV_BGR2GRAY);
                mat_rgb_diff_temp = mat_rgb_diff_temp > I_THRESHOLD;
                mat_rgb_diff_temp.convertTo(mat_rgb_diff_temp, CV_32S);
                mat_diff_temp = mat_diff_temp + mat_rgb_diff_temp;

            }
            mat_diff_temp = mat_diff_temp > I_THRESHOLD_2;
            //            mat_diff_temp.convertTo(mat_diff_temp, CV_8U);

            Mat mat_roi = mat_diff_temp.rowRange(0, i_height_basketball);
//            imshow("ROI", mat_roi);
            Moments mm = cv::moments(mat_roi, true); 
            Point p_center = Point(mm.m10 / mm.m00, mm.m01 / mm.m00);
            circle(result, p_center, 3, CV_RGB(0, 255, 0), -1);
            line(result, Point(0, i_height_basketball), Point(result.cols, i_height_basketball), Scalar(225, 0, 0), 1);

        }
        count_frame = count_frame + 1;
        int clk_processing_time = (clock() - clk_start);
        if (count_frame > 1)
            imshow("image", result);
        //        waitKey(0);

        int delay = (1000 / fps) - clk_processing_time;
        if (delay <= 0)
            delay = 2;
        if (waitKey(delay) >= 27)
            break;

    }
    vid.release();
    return 0;
}
```

**Questions:**

1. How to **detect** the **hoop**? I thought of doing with Square detection to detect the square regions around the hoop.
2. What is the **best way of counting** the successful shoots? Or **How to count** ?

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Can some one point me to the best ball tracking algorithms.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I have what I suspect will be a fairly strong baseline: once the ball has commenced its downward arc, if the ball demonstrates significant upward movement again, its a miss. Otherwise, its a basket. This won't catch airballs, but I suspect they're relatively few anyway.

I think you could get a whole lot of mileage out of learning the ball trajectory of a successful shot and not worry too much about the hoop. Furthermore, didn't you say the camera was fixed-position? Doesn't that mean the hoop's always in the same place, and so you could just specify its location?

EDIT:

If you absolutely did have to find the hoop, I'd look for an object (sub-region of the image) of about the same size as the ball (which you say you can track) that's orange. More generally, you could learn a classifier for the hoop based on the training images you linked to, and apply it at a mixture of locations and scales, searching for the best match. You should know its approximate location, i.e. that it's in the upper portion of the image and likely to be to one side or the other. Then you could use proximity features to this identified region in addition to trajectory features to build a classifier for whether the shot succeeded or not.

Comment: Thanks for your input. 
Can you also consider this situation?
1. In many cases , the ball may not even touch the hoop,but still the elevation will be similar to make or shoot.
One of the other uses of Hoop detection is to instruct the user to place the camera correctly before capturing the videos. 
Yes, the camera position is static for a session.And I am not allowed to get any input from the user to specify the Hoop's location.

Comment: I suspect the number of airballs (where the ball doesn't touch the hoop at all) will be pretty low, unless you're filming people just learning the sport. As I said, it's a baseline; but I suspect it will be a strong one.

Comment: And my edit describes what I'd do if I absolutely had to find the hoop.

Comment: I misunderstood the term "Airballs".Now i got it. Thanks again.

Comment: I want to avoid airballs in two scenarios ( 1 & 2 ). Please have a look at this image ( http://snag.gy/i0lJ7.jpg ). For scenario 1, I can avoid using your bouncing ball logic and region of interest around the hoop, if I detect the hoop. For scenario 2 am thinking of how to avoid airrball? And also can you suggest some other good algorithms for ball tracking if possible?

Comment: Scenario 2 will be extremely difficult to detect. I think it's also extremely unlikely to happen---I would worry about other scenarios before I approached this. I suspect there will be some difference in the ball trajectory for a successful shot than a scenario 2 airball, however (there will be slowdown in the ball speed once it contacts the net), which you could characterise by ball deceleration in the vicinity of the net.

Comment: I got a feeling that 2d is not enough here. As you discussed here, detection of significant trajectory change is hard to implement; and air balls are unnoticable patterns from that angle. Why not connect another camera over(or under) the hoop to see if the circular region of the hoop fills up with the ball? You can call airball or not from that info. And you can call "good trajectory" from first camera, and connect these together as "basket".